# c++ object outputs wrong information

Tags: c++, class, object

Hi guys I have created an object for my class and I tried to output it expecting to the output to be BOb, c, and 1900.543, but the output of the program is blank for the name and type and 0 for balance. 
Anybody can help me out and tell me what's wrong that my program's output is not as expected.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Record{

private:

  string newName;
  char newType;
  double newBalance;

public:
  Record(string, char, double);
  Record();
  string getName();
  char getType();
  double getBalance();

};

Record::Record(string name, char type, double balance)
{
   balance = newBalance;
   name = newName;
   type = newType; 
} 
string Record::getName()
{
    return newName;
}
char Record::getType()
{
   return newType;
}
double Record::getBalance()
{
   return newBalance;
} 

int main()
{

  string name = "Bob";
  char type = 'c';
  double balance = 1900.543;


  Record c1(name, type, balance);
  cout << c1.getName() << endl;
  cout << c1.getBalance() << endl;
  cout << c1.getType() << endl;


 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your assignments in `Record::Record` are the wrong way around.

Comment: Check your constructor. Which objects are your class members and which ones are constructor parameters?

Comment: BTW. [This article on debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)  will be helpful now and in all your future programming.

Answer (score 3):

Please try to debug before posting on the forum.

```
Record::Record(string name, char type, double balance)
{
   balance = newBalance;
   name = newName;
   type = newType; 
}
```

Change this to

```
Record::Record(string name, char type, double balance)
    {
       newBalance = balance;
       newName = name;
       newType = type; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This bug occurred because there was no way the compiler could have warned you about it.
To avoid this you can use a constructor initializer list like this:

```
Record::Record(string name, char type, double balance): newBalance(balance), newName(name), newType(type)
{

}
```

Suppose you had reversed the places of the member variables and arguments as you had done in your code:

```
Record::Record(string name, char type, double balance): balance(newBalance), name(newName), type(newType)
{

}
```

The compiler would have indicated this with errors:

```
error: class 'Record' does not have any field named 'balance'
 Record::Record(string name, char type, double balance): balance(newBalance), name(newName), type(newType)
                                                         ^~~~~~~
error: class 'Record' does not have any field named 'name'
 Record::Record(string name, char type, double balance): balance(newBalance), name(newName), type(newType)
                                                                              ^~~~
error: class 'Record' does not have any field named 'type'
 Record::Record(string name, char type, double balance): balance(newBalance), name(newName), type(newType)
```